# How to disable predictive text on Mac OS Catalina on iMessages

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, messages, catalina, autocorrect

How to disable predictive text on Mac OS Catalina? I don't have it on many places, but on iMessages it is always popping up and screwing with my writing. I have everything regarding autocorrect already switched off, but the predictive text interferes still with my writing. How do I disable it? I am talking about this:
[image: interface pops up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved. While having iMessages, opened, go to Edit -> Spelling and Grammar -> uncheck all.

Answer (score 0):

Also want to share some useful actions to solve this:

1. Open Messages app
2. Start write something with wrong spelling
3. Press Right-click on the underlined word
   [image]
4. Spelling and Grammar ->
5. Uncheck Correct Spelling Automatically

And check this option too:

1. The same as 3.
2. Spelling and Grammar ->
   [image]
3. Show Spelling and Grammar
   [image]

Here you can configure spelling language, grammar checking and focused word spelling.